# Navigation viewcontroller programmatically in swift

Tags: swift

I want to present a view controller named BaseViewController which should have navigation so that I could navigate from BaseViewController. I have tried with the following code, but it doesn't help

```
@IBAction func presentBaseViewControllerButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let baseViewController = getViewControllerInstance("Base", storyboardId: "BaseViewControllerID") as! PostServiceViewController

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) //error this viewcontroller has no member window
    var navigationController = UINavigationController()
    var mainView = baseViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) 
    navigationController.viewControllers = [mainView]
    self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    self.presentViewController(baseViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I found the answer. If anyone still struggling for this, here it is

`let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: setupController)
        navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true
        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: you can embed in navigation controller directly from stoyboard rather than doing it  programatically

Comment: yes, but I have to do it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var nav = UINavigationController()
var mainView = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) //ViewController = Name of your controller
nav.viewControllers = [mainView]
self.window!.rootViewController = nav
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: its same what i have done above. And I got the answer and I edited above for the needy one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let baseViewController = getViewControllerInstance("Base", storyboardId: "BaseViewControllerID") as! PostServiceViewController
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: baseViewController!)
self.window?.rootViewController = nav
```

Comment: Thanks but we cant use self.window in our viewController but in app delegate. And, i was suggested to use the code where you can see edited version of my question in this page. Thank you!

Comment: no actually i tested it in AppDelegate.swift 
so i forgot to change it .

Comment: And if you not allow user to back from BaseViewController then i think you have to change root view controller  instead of presentViewController. because in present view controller it not releasing memory of older viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You need to storyboard id as ViewController name

```
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardController") as! DashboardController
    self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This code works me fine.   'let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: setupController)
        navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true
        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)'